# Filter the list item using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Has anyone made a search box that will filter out the list item?

Example I have:
[Search box on the top]

```
<ul>
   <li>
      Item 1
      <ul>
         <li>Item 1-1</li>
         <li>Item 1-2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3
       <ul>
          <li>Item 1-1</li>
          <li>Item 1-2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So the search box will filter and display the item based on the entered search box.

Comment: Are you asking that the list only match what the search box contains?

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852076/javascript-search-in-object-array-like-sql-by-object-key

Comment: @JayBlanchard : yes u r right.the first time page display a full list of UL list item... when user enter search box, will display the result

Comment: example user enter "1" in the search box, so list item "Item 1" , "Item 1-1" and "Item-1-2" will be displayed. the rest are hidden/truncated.

Comment: i think the best word to use is "search and filter treeview"

Comment: check http://jsbin.com/facap/1 code is below in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you setup the search box. But i would recommend you to use jQuery Autocomplete which has got all features you would be looking for.

Anyways, here is a simple code

```
 $("#search").keyup(function() {
   var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   $("#results li").each(function() {
      var string = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      if(string.indexOf(searchText)!=-1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
   });
});
```

In HTML:

You need to wrap the entire results i.e. `li & ul` inside `<div id="results"></div>`

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/facap/1/edit)**

Comment: i love this demo... i am gonna try it on my project and feedback

Comment: Great.. Just a reminder,  In HTML you need to wrap the li within a <div id="results"></div> , will wait for your feedback :)

Comment: i tried it on my code, but it doesn't return FULL correct value. Exmple I hve Women and Men in my list item, Both belongs to separate parent list item.Search result only return Women when I enter "men" in search box

Comment: Also I notice your demo code having "<li>Item 1<ul>" on the first item, which is an incorrect UL item

Comment: I have added the ul to the demo, still its working fine there.

Comment: i suppose it returned Women was due to the case case sensitive when I entered "men". When I try with "Men" , it return full result of "Men" and "Mens Grooming". Can we make it case insensitive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54047/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-redcoder).

Answer (score 0):

for that you can use javascript if items are fixed or if not then you can use ajax.

how?

call function on-change of textbox value and fill value using function

```
function list()
{
  //  filter items from your list and add between <li> and put inside search ul

     document.getElementbyid("search").innerHTML= your filtered list between li tag


}

<input type="text" id="box" onchange="list()">
<ul id="search">

</ul>
```

Comment: He wants to use jQuery.